# Can I return a string from C main() program

Tags: python, c

I know that C program generally ends with return, where we return the status of the  program. However, I want to return a string.

I will be calling the C-executable from a Python script and printing the returned string.
 Since `main` can't return a string, How do I do this?

Comment: how would you personally do it for another C program? this isn't python specific, after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the return value must be an integer (in general)

What you can do is have the C program print out results (using printf, for example) and have the python script read the standard output of the process (popen functions that give access to child_stdout)

Answer (score 3):

No, as per the C Standard `main` should return an `int` and not a `char *` or `char []`.

> **(5.1.2.2.1)** It (main) shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters ... or with two parameters ... or in some other implementation-defined manner

Answer (score 3):

A program never return string. You can output a string to standard output and pipe it in your python code.